# Scala - return a Boolean that is neither True or False

Tags: scala

I have read up on why using "null" in Scala is not encouraged. But I am having trouble with a method which I would like to return an "empty" Boolean that is neither true or false under certain conditions.

```
def exampleMethod (query: String): Boolean =
{  
  var result: Boolean = false
  try
  { 
     //This will take the input query and return "true" or "false" 
     //depending on the state of the database
     result = boolQueryResult.evaluate()
     return result
  }
  catch
  {
     case e: Throwable => logger.info(e.toString)
  }
  logger.info("Something is wrong! I want to return a boolean with nothing in it!")
  return result
  }
```

In the above code, I am using the evaluate() method which will return true or false, and then that value will be returned in the Boolean. But if something goes wrong and the catch block is executed, I want to return a Boolean that is not true or false, to show that there was an error with the input string. In the current version of this method, the Boolean is initialized to "false," which is not ideal because it indicates that evaluate() returned false, not that the catch block was executed. Is there a way to initialize this variable in a way that it will not return "true" or "false" if the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@bipll is right. `Option[Boolean]` is the Scala way to do what you want. This is how it's done.

```
def exampleMethod(query: String): Option[Boolean] =
  try {
    Some(boolQueryResult.evaluate())
  } catch {
      case e: Throwable => logger.info(e.toString)
                           None
  }
```

Comment: I liked a lot of these answers, but this is the solution that I ended up using. I like its simplicity, although I wish there was a way to use a simple Boolean term in Scala to accomplish this. I believe in Java you can simply set a Boolean == null.

Comment: Scala is a _strongly_ typed language. Since `null` is not a boolean value it is not allowed. Many consider Java's loose typing, and constant null-checking, to be a deficiency. If something might-not-exist then that becomes part of the type system via `Option[Boolean]`, `Option[Int]`, `Option[String]`, etc. That way the receiving code cannot forget to check-for-null because accessing a `Boolean` is different than accessing an `Option[Boolean]`.

Answer (score 3):

Although the other answers suggest an `Option` (returning either `Some(true)`, `Some(false)`, or `None`, you lose the error message in the case where `None` is returned. For this reason, I would suggest instead using [Try](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Try.html) with [Either](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html).

An example might look like this:

```
import scala.util.{Either, Left, Right}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
// Notice the return type: we either return the error as a Left(...), or a Right(boolean result)
def exampleMethod (query: String): Either[Throwable, Boolean] = {
  // Is this where you meant to use `query`? It's not used in your original post
  Try(boolQueryResult.evaluate(query)) match {
    case Success(result) => Right(result)
    case Failure(exception) => Left(exception)
  }
}
```

This way, the caller of the method can decide what to do. For example, you can pattern match on the result of this method and turn a `Left(exception)` into `None` while logging an error:

```
val queryResult: Option[Boolean] = exampleMethod("bad_query") match {
  case Right(result) => Some(result)
  case Left(exception) => {
    Logger.warn(s"There was an issue with exampleMethod: ${exception.getMessage}", exception)
    None
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Option` class:

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for the `Try` type

```
def exampleMethod (query: String): Try[Boolean] =
{  
  Try
  { 
     //If this throws an exception, it will be caught within the Try as a Failure
    // and can be handled later, otherwise the result is stored in a Success
     boolQueryResult.evaluate()
  }
}
```

`Try` can wrap an expression that can fail.  It will contain the value in Success, if an exception is thrown, the then the Try will contain that exception instead in a `Failure`.  You can then operate on the value with methods such as `map`, `flatmap` and `foreach`.  Even better would be to modify your evaluate method to return a `Try` or some other appropriate type instead of throwing the exception, but that is not always possible.

`return` is unneccessary and not recommended in Scala.  The result of the last expression in a method will be automatically returned

Another option is to not use `Boolean` at all.  The trouble with `Boolean` is that it can only hold two states while you need three.  Instead of using a wrapper you can create a new ADT that has three states.

```
sealed trait ExampleResult
case object TrueResult extends ExampleResult 
case object FalseResult extends ExampleResult 
case object QueryError extends ExampleResult
```

Because the Trait is sealed, only classes in the same file can extend the trait ExampleResult, so you know that it will always be one of those three options.

You can then write your code like this

```
def exampleMethod (query: String): ExampleResult =
{  
  try
  { 
     //This will take the input query and return "true" or "false" 
     //depending on the state of the database

     if(boolQueryResult.evaluate()){
       return TrueResult
     } else {
       return FalseResult
     }
  }
  catch
  {
     case e: Throwable => logger.info(e.toString)
  }
  logger.info("Something is wrong! I want to return a boolean with nothing in it!")
  return QueryError
  }
```

Comment: A good scala method shouldn't return `Try`. `Exception` in  `Try` is like `Object`: you have no information what to do with it. If you know what kind of error can occur in the method - use `Either`. If not - just propagate error and handle it in a caller code.

Comment: That's rather opinionated and certainly is not an opinion that is universally shared in the Scala community.